# Module Not Found - I have created a Basic React NPM package but getting an Error "Module Not Found"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-publish, npm-package

I have created a basic react npm package using the command **npx create-react-app** following the [geeksforgeeks-create-react-npm-package](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-publish-a-reactjs-component-to-npm/) documentation but after publishing it, getting an error

npm repo link: [k-k-react-header-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-k-react-header-package)

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "k-k-react-header-package";
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>React Practice Remove it!</h1>
            <Header />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Error**

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'k-k-react-header-package' in 'G:\it22\personal\react-practice-remove-it\src'
ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'k-k-react-header-package' in 'G:\it22\personal\react-practice-remove-it\src'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

**I don't how to resolve it.""
**Anyone have any Idea**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't installed your package properly. Make sure you run `npm install kk-react-header-package` before running the app.